# Joining With SQL Function In CakePHP 3

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hi there I want to change this query into cakePHP 3.0 format but the code is not working could you guys can help me to solve this problem?

Normal SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_tag_review.id) AS user_numbers, SUM(user_rating.rating_value) AS rating_value FROM user_tag_review INNER JOIN user_rating ON user_tag_review.id = user_rating.review_id WHERE user_tag_review.recruiter_id = 2 AND user_rating.rating_id = 1
```

CakePHP code that I have used:

```
$review_table = TableRegistry::get('UserTagReview');
        $query = $review_table->find();
        $query->select(["user_numbers" => $query->func()->count("UserTagReview.id")])
                ->hydrate(false)
                ->join(["table" => "user_rating",
                    "alias" => "r",
                    "type" => "INNER",
                    "condition" => ['r.review_id = UserTagReview.id']
                ])
                ->select(["rating_value" => $query->func()->sum("r.rating_value")])
                ->where(["UserTagReview.recruiter_id" => $recruiter_id, "UserTagReview.rating_id = " . 1]);

        $result = $query->all()->toArray();
```

Comment: 'not working' is not helpfull here. Are you sure it's `condition` rather than `conditions` ?

Comment: yes condition option is working when i am joinging but not working any type of sql function....

Comment: It's definitely `conditions`, plural. And please, as @code-kobold mentioned, "doesn't work" is not a proper problem description, please always be as specific as possible, and describe what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think simpler way to migrate that SQL to Cake is `fields` options in finder:

```
$table = TableRegistry::get('UserTagReview');

$result = $table
    ->find('all' , [
        'fields' => [
            'user_numbers' => 'COUNT(UserTagReview.id)', 
            'rating_value' => 'SUM(user_rating.rating_value)'
        ], 
        'join' => [
            [
                'table' => 'user_rating', 
                'alias' => 'user_rating', 
                'type' => 'INNER', 
                'conditions' => [
                    'UserTagReview.id = user_rating.review_id'
                ]
            ]
        ], 
        'conditions' => [
            'UserTagReview.recruiter_id' => 2, 
            'user_rating.rating_id' => 1

        ]
    ])
->hydrate(FALSE)
->toArray();
```

Maybe this code is not 100% correct, but focus on `fields` array - if we use this as associative array, we can evaluate any sql:

```
'fields' => [
    'alias' => 'COUNT(IF(1,1,0))'
]
```

Comment: One could use raw SQL with `select()` too, but it's usually best to avoid that. It should also be noted that it's better to use the query builder API, it's less error prone and provides proper contextual help in an IDE.